# 2 arrays with json problem (Node.js, Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The first array is:

```
[
  {
    id: "megaphone",
    name: "Megaphone",
    kind: "Consumable",
    description: "Unmutes you if you are currently muted",
    price: 10,
  },
  {
    id: "expcharge",
    name: "Exp Charge",
    kind: "Consumable",
    description: "Double exp for an hour",
    price: 50,
  },
  {
    id: "commonlootbox",
    name: "Common Lootbox",
    kind: "Consumable",
    description: "Chance for a random amount of coins or an item",
    price: 1,
  },
];
```

The second part of the JSON I need is into a JSON file.

I tried to add the data of the json like this:

```js
arr.forEach((a) => {
  no.push(shop.find((i) => i.id === a.name));
});
```

And this is perfect, because i get only the data i need.
But the result is that i have two arrays now.
The second is:

```
[
  { name: "megaphone", quantity: 5 },
  { name: "expcharge", quantity: "3" },
  { name: "commonlootbox", quantity: "3" },
];
```

Now, what I need to do is basically for Each object in the array, I need to do
"array1.name - array2.quantity (array1.description)"

I need to post it like
Megaphone - 5 (Unmutes you if you are currently muted)
Common Lootbox - 3 (Double exp for an hour)
etc.

Hope this is clear.
Maybe my method is wrong?

Comment: I think you need to merge both arrays in order to get the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you need to itirate over the second array and make strings of the result that you want, like so

```
const secondArray = [
{name: 'megaphone', quantity: 5}
{name: 'expcharge', quantity: '3'}
{name: 'commonlootbox', quantity: '3'}
]

const desiredarray = secondArray.map(item => {
    const matchedItem = data.find(({ id }) => id == item.name)

    return `${matchedItem.name} - ${item.quantity} (${matchedItem.description})`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could store one or both arrays in a Map or directly in an object.
You could try something like this:

```
obj = array.reduce((obj, element) => {
    obj[element.id] = element;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Now you can iterate one of the arrays and access the corresponding value in the other one directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could do something like this:

1. Solution with array of JSON:

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 'megaphone', name: 'Megaphone', kind: 'Consumable', description: 'Unmutes you if you are currently muted', price: 10},
{id: 'expcharge', name: 'Exp Charge', kind: 'Consumable', description: 'Double exp for an hour', price: 50},
{id: 'commonlootbox', name: 'Common Lootbox', kind: 'Consumable', description: 'Chance for a random amount of coins or an item', price: 1}];

const arr2 = [{name: 'megaphone', quantity: 5},
{name: 'expcharge', quantity: '3'},
{name: 'commonlootbox', quantity: '3'}];

let arr3 = arr1.map(item1 => {
             let ok_el = {};
             arr2.map(item2 => {
             if (item1.id === item2.name) {
              ok_el.id = item1.id;
              ok_el.name = item1.name;
              ok_el.quantity = item2.quantity;
              ok_el.description = item1.description;
              return ok_el;
           }
        });
    return ok_el;
});

let result = arr3.map(el => {
 return el.name + " - " + el.quantity + " (" + el.description + ")";
});

console.log(result);
```

2. Solution with JSON of JSONs:

```js
const arr1 = {0:{id: 'megaphone', name: 'Megaphone', kind: 'Consumable', description: 'Unmutes you if you are currently muted', price: 10},
    1:{id: 'expcharge', name: 'Exp Charge', kind: 'Consumable', description: 'Double exp for an hour', price: 50},
    2:{id: 'commonlootbox', name: 'Common Lootbox', kind: 'Consumable', description: 'Chance for a random amount of coins or an item', price: 1}};

    const arr2 = {0:{name: 'megaphone', quantity: 5},
    1:{name: 'expcharge', quantity: '3'},
    2:{name: 'commonlootbox', quantity: '3'}};
    
    let arr3 = Object.values(arr1).map(item1 => {
                 let ok_el = {};
                 Object.values(arr2).map(item2 => {
                 if (item1.id === item2.name) {
                  ok_el.id = item1.id;
                  ok_el.name = item1.name;
                  ok_el.quantity = item2.quantity;
                  ok_el.description = item1.description;
                  return ok_el;
               }
            });
        return ok_el;
    });
    
    let result = arr3.map(el => {
     return el.name + " - " + el.quantity + " (" + el.description + ")";
    });

    console.log(result);
```